# Sum of digits of perfect square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, perfect-squares

Prove that the repeated sum of the digits of a perfect square can only be 1,4,7 or 9. Example- 169- Sum-16, Sum of digits of 16 = 7. Please try to explain without log, mods. I am a grade 10th student. Thank You.

Comment: Yes, the question is incorrect. It is correct if you do repeated digit sums - $625\to 13\to 4$.

Comment: Another answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125797/find-all-possible-sum-of-digits-of-perfect-squares)

Answer (score 3):

**Lemma 1**: a natural number and the sum of its digits yield the same remainder when you divide them by $9$.

**Lemma 2**: if $n$ is a perfect square, the remainder of $n/9$ is $0,1,4$ or $7$.

**Lemma 3**: the repeated sum of the digits of a perfect square is $1,4,7$ or $9$.

It is not very hard to prove the first two lemmas, and the third should come easily with the first two.

*Hint for Lemma 1*: every natural number $m$ is $(a_k10^k-a_{k-1}10^{k-1}+\cdots+10a_1+a_0)$, where the $a_j$'s are its digits. Is $m-(a_k+a_{k-1}+\cdots+a_1+a_0)$ a multiple of $9$?