# Which positive integers under 2007 are the digit-sum of a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

> A positive integer $n$ is said to be *good* if there exists a perfect square whose sum of digits in base $10$ is equal to $n$. For instance, $13$ is good because $7^2=49$ and $4+9=13$. How many good numbers are among the list $\{1, 2, 3, \dotsc, 2007\}$?

I input all the numbers from $1$ to $2007$ into an Excel spreadsheet, squared all the numbers, split the squares into individual digits, added the digits and checked-off on the numbers which are repeating in the original list of numbers from $1$ to $2007$, and the sum of digits of the squares.

But this method takes too long. Is there a smarter way to answer this question?

Comment: The only thing that could be “improved” in your approach is to get a script to do the pieces of work for you that you did in the spreadsheet.  Otherwise the method is correct...

Comment: How do you know that the square is the square of a number $\le 2007$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael : I understood from the question that the square is the square of a number <=2007.   :-S

Comment: I believe I am wrong in understanding the question. ...   :-(

Comment: I've made some edits to your post for grammar, and to make the title more descriptive. I hope the edits are to your liking.

Comment: The sequence is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A004159 and there are some links to the literature.

Comment: I think the answer posted to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125797/find-all-possible-sum-of-digits-of-perfect-squares answers your question.

Comment: Have you looked at the link I gave, Math?

Answer (score 0):

Remember the trick about casting out nines.  Summing the digits of a number maintains the remainder on division by $9$.  If we work $\bmod 9$ the only squares are $0,1,4,7$, so any number that is not equivalent to one of these will not have a square with that digit sum.

The next part is to show that any number of this form has a square with that digit sum.  The sum of digits function is like a logarithm. It is at most $9$ times the number of digits of the original number. To get a digit sum of $2017$ you need a number with hundreds of digits, so I am sure you didn’t get close.

You can find patterns of numbers to handle whole classes of desired sums.  If you square $10^k-1$, which is a number with $k\ 9's$ you get $10^{2k}-2\cdot 10^k+1,$ which has $k-1\ 9's,$ an $8,\ k-1 0$'s and a $1$ for a sum of $9k$.  That covers all the multiples of $9$.

Comment: $7$ is also a square mod $9$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael:  right you are.  I stopped too soon because $3^2\equiv 0$

Comment: @RossMillikan: Please explain the trick about casting out nines.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I still don't understand the solution, unfortunately.   :-S   Please can you give an example?

Comment: For example, $5$ is not a square mod $9$, i.e. there is no integer $x$ such that the remainder on division of $x^2$ by $9$ is $5$, so 
neither $5$ nor anything of the form $5 + 9 n$ can't the the digit sum of a square.  On the other hand, $121 = 4 + 9 \cdot 13$ and $4$ is a square mod $9$, so there could be some integer whose square has sum of digits $121$.

Comment: You could see [Wikipedia on modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).  It is a ring like the integers so you can add, subtract, and multiply.  When the modulus is not prime, as here, you can have $ab=0$ even though neither $a$ nor $b$ is zero.